# How do I find the maximim number of iterations in a 4-tuple ducci series given some parameters for a, b, c and s?

Tags: python, math

As mentioned in the title, I am trying to solve a math problem where I need to find the maximum number of iterations (M) of a 4-tuple ducci series. The question is below.

Assign four nonnegative integers to the corners of a square, which we designate the active square. During a step, for each side of the active square, the absolute difference between the numbers on that side’s endpoints is assigned to its midpoint. Then these four new midpoints are connected into a new square (tilted 45 degrees from the previous). This new smaller square becomes the active square. Continue these steps until the active square has all zeroes on its corners.

Define f(a, b, c, d) to be the total number of squares drawn during this process when beginning with the numbers (a, b, c, d) written on the starting square in clockwise order. For example, given a starting arrangement of (10, 6, 3, 1), we would get the sequence of

(4, 3, 2, 9)

(1, 1, 7, 5)

(0, 6, 2, 4)

(6, 4, 2, 4)

(2, 2, 2, 2)

(0, 0, 0, 0)

where the game ends (pictured above). So f(10, 6, 3, 1) = 7. And trivially, f(0, 0, 0, 0) = 1.

Consider the set S = {(a, b, c, d) | a, b, c, and d are all integers with 0 <= a, b, c, d <= 10,000,000}. Let M be the maximum value f obtains on S. Find (a, b, c, d) in S with minimum sum (a+b+c+d) where f(a, b, c, d) = M. Enter your answer as a semicolon-separated list, 10;6;3;1 for example.

I first tried this problem using excel solver, and while my solution is correct, it is too big of a calculation for my laptop.

I then tried it in python, I have found a way to make and check ducci sequences using the code below, but not to actually find the answer to the question.

```py
def ducci_sequence(*ns):
    while True:
        yield ns
        ns = tuple(abs(ns[i - 1] - ns[i]) for i in range(len(ns)))

def ducci(*ns):
    known = set()
    for ns in ducci_sequence(*ns):
        print(ns)
        if ns in known or set(ns) == {0}:
            break
        known.add(ns)
    return len(known) + 1
print(ducci(0, 24, 68, 149), "steps")
```

This will output:
(0, 24, 68, 149)
(149, 24, 44, 81)
(68, 125, 20, 37)
(31, 57, 105, 17)
(14, 26, 48, 88)
(74, 12, 22, 40)
(34, 62, 10, 18)
(16, 28, 52, 8)
(8, 12, 24, 44)
(36, 4, 12, 20)
(16, 32, 8, 8)
(8, 16, 24, 0)
(8, 8, 8, 24)
(16, 0, 0, 16)
(0, 16, 0, 16)
(16, 16, 16, 16)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
17 steps

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please format your code correctly

Comment: what do you mean "the maximm" ?  the question has computed the number of steps....

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that there is an alternative to exhaustive search of `S`?  Any maths?